# Canonical topology for big infinity topoi

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory

It is well known that for $E$ a Grothendieck topos, (by appropriately making use of universes) $E$ carries the canonical Grothendieck topology generated by jointly surjective epimorphisms, say $J$, such that $Sh_J\left(E\right) \simeq E$. Is there an analogous statement for infinity topoi?

Comment: You may have a look at Remark 6.3.5.17 and Lemma 6.3.5.28 in Lurie's book.